# What is the full name of XX in JVM options?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

While reading [the documentation of JDK1.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html#BABDJJFI), I'm very curious about the abbreviation XX.

Take `-XX:ErrorFile=filename` for example, no question about the usage, can any one tell me the full name of the abbreviation XX ?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, it's not some abbreviation, see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html (section "Categories of Java HotSpot VM Options")

Comment: I doubt there's any real (non-arbitrary) reason for it. I doubt it's an abbreviation. Seems like `-X` was chosen for nonstandard, and `-XX` in the same vein.

Comment: `-X` may have been taken from eXperimental or eXtension. The double X means it is less likely to be standard.

Comment: Ao**x**omo**x**oa

Comment: It's stupid. I hate writing those kind of thing which has no underlying meaning. Same goes for abbreviation like maxPermSize, just call it maximumPermanentSize, what is "perm" ? Permission ? Permeable ? I hate this kind of thing in programming where apparently it's fine to just remember that kind of crap by heart instead of actually remembering it because it make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer I could find is at http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.lnx.70.doc/diag/appendixes/cmdline/commands_jvm_xx.html. Quoting from the link :

> Java VM command-line options that are specified with -XX: are not checked for validity. If the VM does not recognize the option, the option is ignored. These options can therefore be used across different VM versions without ensuring a particular level of the VM.

Comment: I don't think this really addresses the question of why XX was chosen.

Comment: That might be true for IBM’s JVM, but HotSpot *does* check these options. This in turn implies that you cannot use them across different JVM versions the way the cite claims and, in fact, the problems with the idea of using such options for different JVMs do not arise when the other JVM does not recognized them, but when it *does*, despite working entirely different…

Answer (score 0):

It's a long programming tradition to use "dash" or "double-dash" command-line parameters. Likewise, using the same letter twice means "even more so". So "-v" for verbose, "-vv" for even more verbose. "X" means "unknown" or "hidden" or even "dangerous".

Comment: I always assumed it was "eXtended".  At least comments in the [javac source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/langtools/file/440c45c2e8ce/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/main/Option.java) suggest that's the case for the javac command: `/** An extended option, documented by -X. */`